# i have a form to create new users, but dont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, authentication

i have a problem with a form to create a user... this is my code of "new"

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
    <div class="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <%= message %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Registrarse" %></div>
<% end %>
```

and "create" in controller

```
def create
   @user = User.new(params[user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_back_or_to root_url, :notice => "Usuario Registrado Satisfactoriamente!"
    else
      render :new, :notice => "No se ha podido registrar"
    end
end
```

when i create the user, this go to login form, and a receive a message empty, because i have an "if" if i have message, this show me a div with some css, so i can see that an error ocurred, but this come empty, what i have wrong? i dont see anything... and of course, the user is not created.!
thanks for the help, i am a newbie in ruby. and sorry for my bad english xd

Comment: What are the server logs saying?

Comment: `@user = User.new(params[:user])` notice the colon before user for the params.

Comment: should `@user = User.new(params[user])` be `@user = User.new(params[:user])`? If its not a typo.

Comment: sorry, i was just testing with user instead :user, but is the same, dont work... this dont create the user, and show me an empty message

Comment: i find my problem, was this:
before_filter :require_login , :except => :new
i was doing a require_login and just except for new, and i need to except :create too. then just edit this line with
before_filter :require_login , :except => [:new, :create]
and thats it, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you most likely are referencing `password_confirmation` which is usually an input tag. You most likely do not have this field in your database as it would just be horrible practice. Are you salting your passwords?

Check out [sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) on github and the Railscasts. It does a nice job on covering authentication.

Also, you need to use `:user` in the `params` => `User.new(params[:user])`

Comment: i find my problem, was this:
before_filter :require_login , :except => :new
i was doing a require_login and just except for new, and i need to except :create too. then just edit this line with
before_filter :require_login , :except => [:new, :create]
and thats it, thanks for your help, and thanks for the video, i am using sorcery ;)

Comment: Ryan's video is a little outdated. Most of his code is still good to use from the video. However, the documentation on Sorcery's github page is much better. ALso, they show examples of how to handle password resets.

Comment: i need the reset password, but with secret answer and question, because thats the requirement, but sorcery reset the password with a email.

Comment: You could always fork the Sorcery repository and create a new method for resetting the password. However, it may be easier to create your own controller or action to reset the password with a secret question. The reset password method in Sorcery generates a token that is used to do the reset of the password. If the reset password URL have the correct token, it will associate the password update with that user.

Comment: ok, then the best way to do it, is creating a new method in sorcery? yeah, i read about that, but the users will be retired workers and most of them dot have a email :-/ then i have to do the reset password with a question and answer, thanks for the tip, ill try with a method in sorcery.

Comment: It may not be necessary to pull the sorcery repository since what you're doing is outside of the scope of what sorcery does. It will probably be best to create a new controller/action to handle this.